# Why does using next() with an update cursor nested inside a Search cursor yield such weird results

Tags: arcpy, cursor, sorting

I did this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(
        in_table = in_table, field_names = '*', where_clause = "",
        sql_clause = (None, "ORDER BY date"))\
        as ordered_cursor:

        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(
            in_table = in_table, field_names = '*')\
            as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                row = next(ordered_cursor)
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I expected this to sort my table by date. Something like this,

```
1 3 5 1/02/1300
6 9 7 1/03/1300
9 9 8 6/09/1342
7 7 7 7/07/1777
```

What I got was something along the lines of,

```
1 3 5 1/02/1300
1 3 5 1/02/1300
6 9 7 1/03/1300
1 3 5 1/02/1300
```

Why did this happen? Is `ordered_cursor` still iterating over the values of `in_table`? I noticed that I was unable to delete the table after I did this while I had the python window that the code executed in open. This was the result of a schema lock. I just want to clarify that this code executes without raising an exception.

I tried using sort management and it doesn't work where I'm using Enterprise connections. I'm not looking for a way to make sort management work. I'm also not looking for a way to sort things. I'm just looking for an explanation of this behavior.

Comment: Where are you using `itertools`?

Comment: Nesting cursors is usually the slow/awkward solution. Nesting two accesses to the same table, with the *inner* cursor writing updates is reason enough for undefined behavior. Depending on the sizes involved, I'd look for a way to cache the desired values in a dictionary, or if it's an enterprise table, use a SQL cursor to eliminate the round-trips.

Comment: You have got a confusion on at least two concepts. (1) The cursors cannot change  order of the table it is reading as long as you are not inserting your sorted results to another feature class row by row. (2) Once you put a cursor on a table, it gets locked depending on your cursor type, therefore if you first start reading your rows, you cannot update but vice versa. Still, the item(1) applies in (2) case. I am not saying anything new here than what @Vince said.

Comment: As a workaround, you can first read your values into a python dictionary and insert sorted results to your source table via InsertCursor. But you need to delete the original (unsorted) rows afterwards at the top of the table.

Comment: @Aaron I'm not here, but it saves memory and executes faster if you use it right.

Comment: @fatih_dur That's actually all wrong. The update cursor is updating my tables. I'm not getting a schema lock when I try to update. I'm getting a schema lock when I try to delete the table. I'll edit that in. Part of why I'm asking this question is to document this strange behavior. Your dictionary comment is spot on though.

Comment: @Steve I do not see `itertools` being used in the Update Cursor.

Comment: @Aaron the cursor returned by the cursor methods in arcpy are iterators and `next()` isn't part of `itertools` so you can use it without import itertools so for this snippet `ordered_cursor` is an iterator cursor object made by `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` and the `next()` function returns the next tuple in the iterator. No `itertools` required here. Someone correct me if I'm wrong. I honestly thought your question was "why are you using `itertools`" hahaha my mistake. Time to edit my question title.

Comment: `next()` is a built-in python function. Sorry if I'm not catching this. Your title mentions `itertools`, however, I do not see any use of `itertools` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) in your code snippet.

Comment: @Aaron yeah haha I saw that and edited it.

Comment: @Steve, please have a look at python [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), the `da` cursor creates one instance of it. Again, the cursor is a generator. That means when you define your cursor, it does not save all your rows in an iterator (list or tuple of tuples) but waits the next() method call. I advise you to first print all your rows (or first 30 at least) as sorted and not sorted in a separate medium (textpad, MS Word, Excel) and print your row tuples along the way for comparison. You will see the cursor functions normal.

Comment: For the lock, try `del row` or better end python session before deleting table.

Comment: @fatih_dur that's not what del row does.  The context manager should take care of deleting the cursor. So what you're saying is that the cursor continuously reads from the table here and that's why the insert cursor is acting so strangely? If so, could you answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

Dont nest the cursors and your code should work.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'X:\database.gdb'
fc = 'table123'
datefieldname = 'date'

fieldlist = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(dataset=fc) if not f.name.upper().startswith(('OBJ','SHAPE'))]
fieldlist.append('SHAPE@') #Delete row if input is only a table without geometries

scursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fieldlist, sql_clause = (None,"ORDER BY {0}".format(datefieldname)))

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldlist) as ucursor:
    for row in ucursor:
        row = next(scursor)
        ucursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: you use `"ORDERED BY"` in the sql_clause part of the cursor to return a generator of sorted rows from the table.

Comment: Can you include the close statement in this answer? Esri changed the documentation examples for `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`